# Devise trackable could not save User, RuntimeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

This happens only for some users when signing in (heroku production)
From the logs:

```
    Started POST "/users/sign_in?locale=en"

     RuntimeError (Devise trackable could not save #<User id:

    cache: [POST /users/sign_in?locale=en] invalidate, pass
```

The 5 devise Trackable database columns are on the user model and have valid looking values for this user. User cannot log in

This is happening since upgrading to devise 2.2.3 from 1.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were active record validation errors on an associated model being saved at the same time